# Struggling to display value of textbox in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been learning JavaScript for 2 weeks now. I want to print the value of the textbox in a p element, but not managing.... Any help????

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>First Name:
<input  id="firstName" type="text"></input>
</p>

<p>Last Name:
<input  id="lastName" type="text"></input>
</p>

<button onClick="message()">Click here to see message!</button>

<p id="message"></p>

<script>
    function message() {
        let firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
        let lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
        let message = (`Hello ${firstName} ${lastName}, I hope you enjoyed!`);
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=message;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: document.getElementById("input").value

Comment: Use it like " var input = document.getElementById("input").value ". Besides that, indent the code before posting. And It is good to make variables instead of fetching element and making changes with it in one statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hie Your code is almost correct you just need to add document on input variable. check code below.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="input" type="text"><br><br>
        <button onclick="printInput()">Click to see your text in paragraph</button>
        <p id="par"></p>
   
    <script>
        function printInput() {
                        var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
                        document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = input;
}
            </script>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh! Of course!! Thank you so much. Tried it and works!

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` is a node method, not a window method. It is specific to nodes only, and is not part of the window object. You should use `document.getElementById()` instead. You should search the document for the element with ID `input`, not the window object.

```js
function printInput() {
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = input;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text"><br><br>
<button onclick="printInput()">Click to see your text in paragraph</button>
<p id="par"></p>
```